# How can I use pyinstaller to build a macos app on an apple silicon mac for x86_64 intel macs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, apple-m1

I have a tool which I build to a .app using pyinstaller. I now need it to run on intel macs as well as M1 macs. How can I do this?

I've tried simply targeting x86_64 or universal2 but neither of those options seem to work.

Targeting x86_64 gives the expected issues:

`PyInstaller.utils.osx.IncompatibleBinaryArchError: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/array.cpython-39-darwin.so is incompatible with target arch x86_64 (has arch: arm64)!`

and targeting universal2 gives me

`PyInstaller.utils.osx.IncompatibleBinaryArchError: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-39-darwin.so is not a fat binary!`

I'm pretty comfortable with python by pyinstaller is new to me, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need a build for `arm64` architecture

Comment: Note that you need an x86_64-compatible Python installed -- the error message is telling you that you don't have one. If the steps in the duplicate don't help, [edit] to show details of how you attempted to follow that advice here -- not just saying "targeting x86_64", but showing how you attempted it in enough detail to let someone reproduce the issue; @-notice me when those edits are done and I'll reopen. (As a further note to help in understanding the error messages: a "fat binary" is a library or executable that has instructions for _both_ architectures created at compile time).

Comment: @eshirvana, but the OP is trying to build binaries for use on x86_64, not arm64, even though arm64 is their local platform.

Comment: (I do have a pretty good idea of how I'd tell [Nix](https://nixos.org/) to install an x86_64 Python interpreter on an arm64 Mac, but no idea how to do that with Homebrew or if homebrew even _can_ do it at all; personally, I stay away from Homebrew on account of its outright dangerous security model).